# NSScanner to separate sentence into words (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I have a string "So: lets make some noise!" and I would like it to be displayed one word at a time on the screen. How can I go about this? NSScanners? I am new to objective C and really need some help... thank you!

for example. the first word i see is "So:" the second word i see is "Lets"...with the last word being "noise!"
It must be case sensitive and only cut out spaces.
I also need to be able to control the speed at which the words are displayed.

If you can help me I will be eternally grateful :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
```